# MySQL select, embedded cursor

Tags: mysql, oracle, select, cursor

For example I have database, where I have two tables QUESTIONS and ANSWERS. One question can have multiple answers, so QUESTIONS table has one to many relation with ANSWERS table.

In Oracle to select one question, with all it's answers I can write following select:

```
select q.*,
       cursor (select a.*
               from ANSWRES a
               where a.question_id = q.question_id) as answers
from QUESTIONS q
where q.question_id = 123;
```

Is it possible to write similar select in MySQL database ?

If not, what are alternative ways two get question, with all it's answers using one select ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a `join`:

```
select q.*, a.*
from QUESTIONS q left outer join
     ANSWERS a
     on a.question_id = q.question_id
where q.question_id = 123;
```

Comment: This will help in simple situations, but when you have some table which is in one to many relation with multiple tables, then I think embedded cursors are more clear and intuitive solution in this situation.

Comment: @Yoh0xFF . . . Although I disagree with you (because having operators in the `select` clause affect the number of rows violates the "intention" of `select`), the more important issue is that embedded cursors are quite specific to Oracle, whereas this answer is standard SQL syntax that should work in any SQL database.

Comment: A "master with multiple details" query is a challenge in plain SQL. while you can use a JOIN to get all related data this is not ideal as the rows of various detail tables are only bound to the common master, but not related to each other so they still form a cartesian product. Such a query like performs poorly (not just in MySQL) and will be painful to process by the receiver.

You can emulate the "embedded cursor" by aggregation using GROUP_CONCAT. This creates a list of strings, which you can re-parse in the client, which may be slighly less painful.

Another viable approach is to send...

Comment: ...multiple queries as a batch, and receive multiple resultsets (one for each detail). I feel this has the advantage as compared to "embedded cursors" since this is a portable mechanism that neither relies on any result set parsing, nor relies on any specific API to access individual items delivered by the embedded cursor.